# Posting empty dictionary to ASP.NET MVC4 action with Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using jquery to post dictionary to my controller action:

Client-side code:

```
var dict = {};
// var dict = {"type": "type-1"}; // this works fine
$.post('/MyController/MyAction?id=' + jsId + '&data=' + jsData, { additionalFields : dict }, function () { //some callback });
```

Server-side code:

```
    public ActionResult MyAction([FromUri]Guid id, [FromUri]string data, [FromBody]Dictionary<string, string> additionalFields)
    {
        //some code
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

If there are no additional data and dict variable is empty I receive strange data at the server side:
additionalFields dictionary will contain two entries:

**controller**: MyController

**action**: MyAction

How i can fix it?

Here is picture that shows server-side data when i'm posting empty dictionary:
[image: strange]

Answer (score 1):

try setting dict to null before posting to server when dictionary doesn't contain values

```
dict = null;
```

Comment: I had the exact same problem with MVC5 and I had to write  `dict = "null";` to make it work. I still don't understand why.... I just let it here if it can help someone in the future

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the ModelBinder has picked some data in the body of the "Post" request. Why do you need [FromBody] attribute?

Try remove it and that should resolve your issue.

Comment: That probably has nothing to do with this. I'm having the same problem without attributes. Looks like a bug in mvc.